# How can I use packages in Java and Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, package

I imported the packages tcpcommclient and tcpcommserver from this repo [here](https://github.com/roman10/roman10-android-tutorial) to my eclipse. I created a new project called Ygen. Then I wanted to use the packages: their objects, methods, etc but it does not realize the packages in my Eclipse environment like below, why?

[image]

Comment: @Fredrik I did it with iPad's ProCreate -app, very fast usage for this kind of communication. Jätte bra!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are they added to `Build Path`?

Comment: Thank you +1, `"Project > Properties > Build Path"` in Eclipse and the bug fixed! http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/ref-properties-build-path.htm